# How to load Spring Application context in Maven tests

Tags: spring, maven, junit, junit4

I have a **Maven web project** where I want to execute some JUnit integration tests. To achieve that, I want to load the *applicationContext.xml* file to obtain the Spring injected beans. Also my application context files are located into `src/main/resources/app_context`, but when executing Maven's lifecycle, it's locating them into `WEB-INF/classes/application_context`, so I'm able to access them through the classpath.

```
<resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources/appcontext</directory>
    <targetPath>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/application_context</targetPath>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
    <includes>
        <include>*/**</include>
    </includes>
</resource>
```

I have tried to access that context in some ways, but without succeeding. I'm also putting them into Maven's target test directory in that way:

```
<testResources>
    <testResource>
        <directory>
                src/main/resources/appcontext
            </directory>
        <targetPath>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/application_context</targetPath>
    </testResource>
</testResources>
```

This is a piece of my Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:**/applicationContext.xml" })
@Transactional
public class SystemTest {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Test
    public void initializeSystemTest() {
            //Test code
```

And that's how I have access to the rest of the application context files from my main one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:application_context/ApplicationContext*.xml" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <!--========== Spring Data Source ========== -->
    <!--Bean stuff-->
```

Basically I want to have only a copy of each one of the applicationContext files stored in `src/main/resources` and let Maven copy them for test and execution scopes. However my test classes are unable to find and load them. What I have to do?

Comment: Why are you copying from `appcontext` to `application_context`? That is just going to confuse issues. Why not just use the defaults, in which case `src/main/resources/appcontext` will end up in `WEB-INF/classes/appcontext`? It will also be easier on your SCM, because you won't end up with changes in `src` when you build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `applicationContext.xml` is in `src/main/resources/appcontext`, Maven will realocate it in `WEB-INF/classes/appcontext` by default. It's not necessary to assign a new path for that resource.

You should be able to find the context file in your test with:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/appcontext/applicationContext.xml"})
```

You shouldn't need additional Maven settings for this.

Comment: I have them stored in `/src/main/resources/appcontext`, however if I try in that way I have this error `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [appcontext/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [appcontext/applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist`

Comment: But isnt your Maven plugin copying them to here: /classes/application_context. Check where they are in the build dir. What happens when you use: `@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/application_context/applicationContext.xml"})`

Comment: Yes, it's copying them there. I have this log before the tests are executed. `[INFO] Using 'ISO-8859-1' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources to C:\Users\amaeztu\workspace\System_Maven/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/application_context` but later when tests are executed I've got a `java.io.FileNotFoundException` error with this dir too.

Comment: So you get the FileNotFound when you specify the location as /application_context/applicationContext.xml as well?

Comment: I think it would be useful to check thebuild directory. Does your project build to a target folder if so look in there? When you copy to `${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/application_context` is it definitely the same structure in the resulting build directory

Comment: Skipping the tests and building the project I can see them located into `target/system/WEB-INF/classes/application_context` directory.

Comment: I have update my `pom.xml` to let the resources be moved to the default directory and now it works with `locations = { "/appcontext/applicationContext.xml" }`. Many thanks for your advices.

Comment: Great, simpler is better :)